# Delta function propogation in the NLS regime

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, schrodinger-operators

consider the $(1+1)D$ or $(2+1)D$ NLS:
$$ i\psi _t (t,{\bf x}) + \Delta \psi + |\psi|^2\psi = 0 \, ,$$
$$ \psi (t,|{\bf x}|\to \infty) =0 \, , \quad  \psi(t=0,{\bf x}) = \psi_0 ({\bf x}) \, , $$
with $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$, $d=1,2$,  $t\geq0$. Usually, the discussion about solutions or blow-up of the NLS is for $\psi_0 \in H^1$, and there is some work about "rougher" initial condition.

**My question:** is what sort of analysis is done for the case of $\psi_0  = \delta ({\bf x})$. Obviously, this can not be an initial condition in the strict sense, but I do wonder if some work was done in this direction?

**I was referred** to [this work](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIHPC/AIHPC_2008__25_4/AIHPC_2008__25_4_697_0/AIHPC_2008__25_4_697_0.pdf), but I will appreciate further references.

Comment: JFYI: I am slowly slowly removing the "nonlinear" tag. It serves almost zero function (any question for which nonlinearity plays a significant row can be found using that word, and I would wager at least 30 or 40 % of all questions on MO concern "nonlinear" objects anyway).